# Git Bash in windows won´t start

Tags: windows, git, shell, sh, git-bash

I´m really new using Git Bash so sorry in advance if my description is a little rough.

I was trying to use python inside Git Bash for windows so i followed this instructions: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M33oOq-c60s&t=2s&ab_channel=chinamatt

When I closed and try to re-open Git,it loaded for a few seconds and closed, without any error message,
Now I can´t make it load even unistalling and re- installing it, the only thing I notice is that at the top of the window it says `usr/bin/bash --login i`..
I guess it had to do with the `'. ${HOME}/.bash_profile' ~ /.bashrc` command, but I have no idea since
I´ve had never used `{HOME}` command before.

Comment: I have never used git bash (always working with Cygwin's git), and I don't know what you mean by _opening Git_; but I would first get bash running, and only then worrying about Git. Can you start a bash shell from the Windows command prompt?

Comment: I´ve never tryied that, i downloaded https://git-scm.com/downloads

Comment: So maybe it's time to try now, before we go into debugging more complex stuff? First make sure that the basics work!

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure your git bash works again, by removing any `~/.bahs_profile` and `~/.bashrc`

Second, consider, if you are on the latest Windows 10, to [use WSL2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10), in which you will be able to install/use Python in a familiar Linux environment, as opposed to Git limited mingw/bash.